# Wordpress Feature image restrictions when upload

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, thumbnails, restriction

I am trying to add restrictions when my users upload feature image. I tried to use this function in function.php file but it adds restrictions to all uploading images for users and administrators.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','mdu_validate_image_size');
function mdu_validate_image_size( $file ) {
$image = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
$minimum = array(
    'width' => '1000',
    'height' => '1000'
);
$maximum = array(
    'width' => '1000',
    'height' => '1000'
);
$image_width = $image[0];
$image_height = $image[1];

$too_small = "Image dimensions are too small. Minimum size is {$minimum['width']} x {$minimum['height']} pixels. Uploaded image is $image_width x $image_height pixels.";
$too_large = "Image dimensions are too large. Maximum size is {$maximum['width']} x {$maximum['height']} pixels. Uploaded image is $image_width x $image_height pixels.";

if ( $image_width < $minimum['width'] || $image_height < $minimum['height'] ) {
    // add in the field 'error' of the $file array the message 
    $file['error'] = $too_small; 
    return $file;
}
elseif ( $image_width > $maximum['width'] || $image_height > $maximum['height'] ) {
    //add in the field 'error' of the $file array the message
    $file['error'] = $too_large; 
    return $file;
}
else
    return $file;
```

}

How do I have to change this function to get only feature image's size or what filter do I have to use?

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
   $html = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post_id).'"title="'.esc_attr(get_the_title( $post_id )).'">'.$html.'</a>';
   return $html;
}
```

May be this helps.